# Using shouldBeDisabled to enable / disable controls

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Is using shouldBeDisplay the way to enable / disable a control on the html or it is easier to go with jscript?  I have the follow code (spacebar i believe) but it does not trigger anything.

template:

```
<template name="prodlist">
<select id="category-select">
        <option {{ shouldBeDisabled }} selected="selected">Please Select</option> 
        {{#each prodlist}}
            <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```

helper:

```
Template.registerHelper("shouldBeDisabled", function(prodlist) {
    return "disabled"
});
```

Comment: `disabled=shouldBeDisable` you forgot the `d`: `disabled=shouldBeDisabled`. Does that solve your issue? Also you might need to simply return `"disabled"` instead of an object, drop the `disabled=` part and use Spacebars' helper indicator: `{{ shouldBeDisabled }}`.

Comment: @Kyll I'm don't understand what it means by drop the disabled=part and use {{ shouldBeDisabled }}.  It can be used within <option>?

Comment: I think `disabled=shouldBeDisable` should simply be `{{ shouldBeDisabled }}̀`

Comment: @Kyll thanks Kyll I updated the code in the post, no syntax error but controls are still enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error - the disable should be placed at the **select** not **option**:

```
<template name="prodlist">
<select id="category-select" disabled= {{ shouldBeDisabled }}>
        <option selected="selected">Please Select</option> 
        {{#each prodlist}}
            <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```